# How to add html <a href> tag as a json value in swift

Tags: json, swift, share, point, tasklist

I want to add the MYURL tag as a JSON value and post the JSON data to SharePoint rest api(https://mySite/lists/getbytitle('MyTaskList')/items).

But I'm getting an error that "An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected".

Can someone please help me to resolve this?

This is the code I'm using:

[Code I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE1Tk.png)

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I have added the link to the code I wrote..Kindly check..